# Python socket not receiving all bytes, always missing 1024 bytes

Tags: python, tcp

For some reason, the following code will only write N-1024 bytes, where N is the file size. This occurs when I test it on an image file.

When I tried to test it on a text file that is less than 1024 bytes, it doesn't even enter the if condition in the receiving method, and does not write anything.

```
def server(port):
    # create a communicator object
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    #binds to available interfaces
    serversocket.bind(('', int(port)))

    #listens for conncetions and accept
    serversocket.listen(5)
    sock, addr= serversocket.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=optionHandler, args=[sock]).start()
    threading.Thread(target=optionReceive, args=[sock]).start()


def client(port, server):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((server, int(port)))
    threading.Thread(target=optionHandler, args=[sock]).start()
    threading.Thread(target=optionReceive, args=[sock]).start()

def optionHandler(sock):
    while(True):
        opt = input("Enter an option ('m', 'f', 'x'):\n"
                    " (M)essage (send)\n"
                    " (F)ile (request)\n"
                    "e(X)it\n")

        if opt.lower() == 'f':
            sock.send(opt.encode())
            recvFile(sock)

        elif opt.lower() == 'm':
            sock.send(opt.encode())
            sendMessage(sock)

        elif opt.lower() == 'x':
            break

def optionReceive(sock):
    while(True):
        msg = sock.recv(1024)
        if msg.decode().lower() == 'f':
            sendFile(sock)

        elif msg.decode().lower() == 'm':
            recvMessage(sock)

        elif msg.decode().lower() == 'x':
            print('exit')


def sendMessage(sock):
    msg = sys.stdin.readline()
    sock.send(msg.encode())

def recvMessage(sock):
    msg = sock.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode(), end='')

def sendFile(sock):
    fileName = sock.recv(1024)
    f = open(fileName, 'rb')
    l = f.read(2048)
    while(l):
        print("Sending...")
        sock.send(l)
        l = f.read(2048)
    f.close()
    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print("Done sending")

def recvFile(sock):
    fileName = input("What file do you want to receive?: ")
    sock.send(fileName.encode())
    f = open(fileName, 'wb')
    while (True):
        l = sock.recv(2048)
        print(sys.getsizeof(l))
        if(l):
            print("Writing..")
            f.write(l)
        else:
            break
    f.close()
    print("Done writing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import getopt
    import sys
    import threading
    import socket

    #gets command line arguments
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "l:")

    #run server if the command line includes '-l'
    if len(opts) == 1:
        server(opts[0][1])
    #runs client if there is no '-l' argument
    else:
        client(args[0], args[1])
```

Comment: there's some indentation issues with def server(port). I don't want to fix it up in your post in case I misinterpret where it should be.

Comment: There seems to be no application protocol here. You're reading the filename into a 1024 byte buffer. Almost certainly part of the file is in there as well. You need some way of delimiting the file name, and the file itself.

Comment: Why would part of the file be inside the filename buffer? The filename is sent from the receiving end to the sending end, and the sending end, after receiving the filename, sends the file. I'm confused since at no point is the filename and file itself being sent to the same user.